# Set UIScrollView to start on set page

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView, in which I have three views that the user can swipe between. I want to have the app open up on the middle page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

You can create a CGPoint to the coordinate you want the view to be opened to.

For example, to swipe to the middle page it might look like:

```
CGPoint point = CGPointMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width,0);
```

And then you can set the contentOffset of the UIScrollView like:

```
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:point animated:NO];
```

You can multiply the x-coordinate of the point (`self.scrollView.frame.size.width`) by any number to start on any page (0-indexed), or set it to a completely different number to start at any arbitrary point in the scrollView.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic answer; so quick and helpful! Actually have to wait to set it as the accepted answer!!!

Comment: Still helpful. In case you'd like to start at a specific page within an NSArray I'd suggest using `CGPointMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width*(pageIndex),0);`